# How do you see where an IOC error is?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So I have created a new ASP.NET Core project in Visual Studio and made the updates necessary to get it up and running on beta5. I can pull open a few of the pages but when I go to any serviced by the AccountController I get the following exception

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this
>   object. System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type,
>   Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)

When I look at the message and the call stack nothing points to what class it can't Create. I have gone and removed the EntityFramework Identity provider and have a custom Mongo Identity Provider but it looks like it is configured in the same manner and the error message doesn't point to anything.

Comment: Did you check that the model used by the requested view declare an parameterless constructor ? (ex: a viewmodel without parameterless constructor will throw this error). The same goes for Action parameters in your controller.